# awk to parse field and include the text of 1 pipe

Tags: awk

I am trying to parse the input in `awk` to include the `|gc= in $4` but am not able to.  The below is close:

`awk` so far:

```
awk '{sub(/\|[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[0-9]+/, ""); print }' input.txt
```

**Input**

```
chr1    955543  955763  AGRN-6|pr=2|gc=75   0   +
chr1    957571  957852  AGRN-7|pr=3|gc=61.2 0   +
chr1    970621  970740  AGRN-8|pr=1|gc=57.1 0   +
```

**Current Output**

```
chr1    955543  955763  AGRN-6  +
chr1    957571  957852  AGRN-7  +
chr1    970621  970740  AGRN-8  +
```

**Desired Output** (each field separated by a tab)

```
chr1    955543  955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    +
chr1    957571  957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2  +
chr1    970621  970740  AGRN-8|gc=57.1  +
```

**edit**

```
gawk '{gensub(/\|[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[0-9]+[\]+/, ""); print }' input.txt > output.txt
gawk: cmd. line:1: {gensub(/\|[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[0-9]+[\]+/, ""); print }
gawk: cmd. line:1:          ^ unterminated regexp
gawk: cmd. line:1: error: Unmatched [ or [^: /\|[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[0-9]+[\]+/, ""); print }/
```

Also tried this `awk`, but that just prints the original input:

```
awk '{sub(/\|[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[0-9]+[[|blank|]]+/, ""); print }' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: it looks like your input data is tab delimited. Is that correct? Do you want tab delimited output too? Read about the `split()` function. Good luck

Comment: Do you have GNU awk? If so, gensub() is what you want instead of sub().

Comment: I will read about split and do have GNU `awk` but am not familiar with `gensub()`.  Thank you :).

Comment: I see how `gensub()` can be used but can not get the correct syntax posted in the edit.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

This is close: (doesn't include the `|` but thats no big deal)

```
awk '{split($4,a,"|"); print $1,$2,$3,a[1],a[3],$6}' input.txt
chr1    955543  955763  AGRN-6 gc=75    +
chr1    957571  957852  AGRN-7 gc=61.2  +
chr1    970621  970740  AGRN-8 gc=57.1  +
```

Thank you @shelter :)

Comment: there are several ways to get the `|` char in your output. The most simplest is to just insert into the output string, like `print $1,$2,$3,a[1]"|"a3, $6}'` Note how chars and strings are surrounded with db-quotes, `"|"`, but variables are left unquoted. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'|' '{sub(/ 0 /,"")}{print $1"|"$3}' file
chr1    955543  955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    +
chr1    957571  957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2  +
chr1    970621  970740  AGRN-8|gc=57.1  +
```

First the pipe is used as field separator. The point is to get rid of the the second column. It is replaced by a pipe without any comma to keep column one and three tightly together. Doing that the zeros is still there next to the plus sign. So before the print  action the zeros have to be removed, in this case, by sub and a pattern in order not to remove them all. I used /space0space/.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try multiple stages each very simple and utilizing awk's build-ins

```
$ awk -F'|' '{print $1"|"$3}' file 
    | awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6}' 

chr1    955543  955763  AGRN-6|gc=75    +
chr1    957571  957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2  +
chr1    970621  970740  AGRN-8|gc=57.1  +
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ]+|[|]+"};{print $1,$2,$3"|"$6 }'
```

edit:using gawk

```
gawk '{print gensub(/(^[^|]+)\|[^|]+([|][^+]+).*/,"\\1\\2","g",$0)}' my_file
```